# How to keep react-native app as LTR (left to right)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, right-to-left, left-to-right

I have created a simple chat application with `react-native`, it looks very nice when the `device language` is `left to right`, but on `devices with RTL` (**right to left**) Language it looks very bad and layout is not responsive.

So how Can I `forcefully keep` it as `LTR(left to right)` even on devices with `RTL languages` like `persian, arabic, dari, pashto, urdo`..

Comment: You shouldn't.  You should write your code to support both equally well, or write a separate layout for them if not.  Keeping it LTR will lead to a really shitty experience in those languages.

Comment: Not matter I just want to keep it LTR and dont need to be RTL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way that you could just disable the setting.

```
import { I18nManager} from 'react-native';

I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
export default class Example extends Component {   
    ...
}
```

Comment: It import from [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f0fb228ec76ed49e6ed6d786d888e8113b8959a2/Libraries/Utilities/I18nManager.js) that theory works on both.

Answer (score 1):

**I fixed by adding this code to MainApplication.java**

**And there is no need to add anything in the app.js or else, also the I18nUtil is built in in Reactnative  so there is no need to install it.**

```
// import this at the top
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    @Override`enter code here`
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // FORCE LTR
        I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
        sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
        ....
    }
}
```